# React-leaflet LayersControl throws error when moving code into function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Sorry if it this has been answered somewhere else before! I am new to react-leaflet and struggle with this issue for some time now.

The following code does not compile and and the chrome developer tools tell me: 3 errors on this page:
1) "TypeError: addOverlay is not a function",
2) "TypeError: addOverlay is not a function" and ",
3) "TypeError: this.props.removeLayer is not a function".

What I do not understand is: if I comment out the "TestOverlay" component, it compiles. There seems to happen some magic with putting the code into a function, but I have no clue what is the problem..

Using:
"leaflet": "1.7.1",
"react": "16.14.0",
"react-dom": "16.14.0",
"react-leaflet": "2.7.0",

Thanks a lot for the help!

```
import React from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, LayersControl, Marker, LayerGroup } from "react-leaflet";

import "./App.css";

function TestOverlay() {
  return <LayersControl.Overlay checked name="Random layer 2">
  <Marker position={[52.339545, 4.900526]} />
</LayersControl.Overlay>;

}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Map center={[52.339545, 4.900526]} zoom={14}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <LayersControl position="topright">
        <LayersControl.Overlay checked name="Random layer">
          <Marker position={[52.339545, 4.900526]} />
        </LayersControl.Overlay>
        <TestOverlay/>
      </LayersControl>
    </Map>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation1](https://react-leaflet.js.org/legacy/docs/en/class-hierarchy), [documentation2](https://react-leaflet.js.org/legacy/docs/en/setup)

> Map: top-level component instantiating a Leaflet map and providing it
> to its children.

> All components are React wrappers for Leaflet elements and layers,
> they need a map instance and therefore must be included in a top-level
>  component.

LayersControl.Overlay uses Overlay class( [doc](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/v2/src/LayersControl.js)) and inside Overlay class there is the following code:

```
 class Overlay extends ControlledLayer {
  constructor(props: ControlledLayerProps) {
    super(props)
    this.contextValue = {
      ...props.leaflet,
      layerContainer: {
        addLayer: this.addLayer.bind(this),
        removeLayer: this.removeLayer.bind(this),
      },
    }
  }

  addLayer = (layer: Layer) => {
    this.layer = layer // Keep layer reference to handle dynamic changes of props
    const { addOverlay, checked, name } = this.props
    addOverlay(layer, name, checked)
  }
}
```

in the constructor `addLayer` is assigned a method which is `this.addLayer`.
inside `this.addLayer` addOverlay is being destructured via props. Most likely at that point props do not contain addOverlay method and therefore cannot be retrieved so the error occurs.

As a result you cannot use `LayersControl.Overlay` the way you are trying to. There is not such an example and I think it is not possible as the map instance is not provided the way it should to `LayersControl.Overlay`

Comment: the first two links documentation1, documentation2-> page not found.

Comment: This is because the library owner modified the url links and their content due to new version release and now they do not work.